# How to add custom column into SQL Server Management Studio object explorer details for jobs, alerts, operators

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

How to add custom column into SQL Server 2008 Management Studio's object explorer details for jobs, alerts, operators ? I can't seem to add other information that I wanted.

I notice the column table format in SQL Server 7 provided more and better view.

In SQL Server 7, I could do the see the following in one view. Is Microsoft going backward?

Jobs

```
Name, Category, Enabled, Runnable, Scheduled, Status, Last Run Status, Next Run Date
```

Operators

```
Name, Enabled, Last Mail, Last Paged, Last Net Send
```

Alerts

```
Name, Enabled, Error, Severity, Last Occurred, Email, Pager, Net Send, Count
```

Answer (score 0):

The preferred solution for customizing views in SSMS is [custom reports](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb153684.aspx); there's an example of building a report [here](http://www.sql-server-performance.com/2007/custom-reports-ssms/). This adds a lot more functionality but of course at the price of more complexity and something new to learn. Whether this is a step backwards or forwards is a question of taste, I suppose.